# Dynamically locked cell in not locked range

Tags: excel, vba

In my worksheet, I have locked whole sheet, with password, with not locked range.

Not locked range is `=A14:H50` and I want to make range `=C14:C50` become dynamically locked range based on BX value. Eg. If B14 value  `locked`, C14 should be locked. If B14 value `notlocked`, C14 shouldn't be locked.

There are many codes for dynamically locked cells, but I don't know how it works if whole sheet without range is locked also.

Comment: *Not locked range is =A14:H50* means that Range `B14:B50` is locked. Could you clarify the dynamics? Did you mean `BX14`?

Comment: @VBasic2008: I think he is referring to 'BX' with the signification of 'B10, B11 and so on'. X should be a numeric variable... And the cell to the right, on the same row must be locked according to 'Bx' value.

Comment: So, would you like to (dinamically) execute the locking/unlocking when such a string is inputted in the range "B14:B50"?

Comment: @FaneDuru, exactly. BX reffers to B14, B16 etc. You understood it correctly. And `=A14:H50` is edible range. (According to @VBasic2008 doubts)

Comment: Please, try the solution I provided in my answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next event code in the sheet code module. The code as it is, protect and unprotect without a password. If your sheet is protected with a password, please change the line `pass = ""` in `pass = "myPassword"`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B14:B50")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim pass As String
        pass = "" 'set the password. Otherwise, protection/unprotection is done without a pass
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect pass
        If Target.Value = "locked" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "notlocked" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect pass
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just changed to `        ElseIf Target.Value = "notlocked" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
        End If`and it works fine. I've been using sheet protection with `AllowEditRanges` and I thought it would be the problem. Now Im using just locked/unlocked cells to protect the sheet and its more efficient.

Comment: Although, there is one thing. If I merge some cells in B column I get error, that I cannot add Locked property for a range.

Comment: @Filip Frątczak: Of course you do not. You cannot lock only **a part of a merged cell**... You can try to unmerge it, but the tricky case will be to determine which (unmerged) cell will take the value of the merged one. The top left cell will take it as default. If you want to put it in a different cell it is also possible but firstly memorizing the value and then copy it wherever you need. I mean, programmatically...